# how to make screen scrollable from mid of screen

Tags: android

i want to make screen scrollable this is my full screen

[image]

i want to screen below this:

[image]

are scroll  able how i will do that? in my code only listview scrolable not all ui scrool able i want to make scrollable below three tab "Lunch" breakfast" and Suppper help me please

```
          <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="#ffffff"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

   <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/editbackground" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnback"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/myback" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtCaption2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnback"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="Menues"
        android:textSize="17dp" >
    </TextView>
   </RelativeLayout>

   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

       <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgfourth1"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="33"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:src="@drawable/amlet1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgfourth2"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="33"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:src="@drawable/lnch1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgfourth3"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="33"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:src="@drawable/supper" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border4"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtfth1"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="33"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Breakfast" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtfth2"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="33"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Lunch" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtfth3"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="33"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Supper" />
    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- i want screen below this line scrollable -->

   <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttonlayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60sp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:gravity="left|top"
    android:height="60sp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/last_month"
        android:layout_width="20sp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
        android:src="@drawable/calendar_left_arrow_selector" >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date_today"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="60sp"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#000000" >
    </TextView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/next_month"
        android:layout_width="20sp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginRight="10sp"
        android:src="@drawable/calendar_right_arrow_selector" >
    </ImageView>
      </LinearLayout>

     <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/last_week"
        android:layout_width="50sp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#F2F2F2"
        android:src="@drawable/barrowleft2" >
    </ImageView>

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/table_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:stretchColumns="0,1,2,3,4,5,6" >

        <TableRow
            android:background="#F2F2F2"
            android:paddingBottom="12dp" >

            <!--
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sun"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/sunday"
            android:textColor="#000000"/>

            -->

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mon"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/monday"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tue"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/tuesday"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/wed"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/wednesday"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/thur"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/thursday"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fri"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/friday"
                android:textColor="#000000" />
            <!--
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sat"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/saturday"
            android:textColor="#000000"/>

            -->
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <!--
      <Button
    android:id="@+id/e00"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:background="@drawable/calendar_button_selector"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#D9DBD7" >
       </Button>

            -->

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/e01"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/calendar_button_selector"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#D9DBD7" >
            </Button>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/e02"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/calendar_button_selector"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#D9DBD7" >
      >

            </Button>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/e03"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/calendar_button_selector"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#D9DBD7" >
    >

            </Button>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/e04"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/calendar_button_selector"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#D9DBD7" >
 >

            </Button>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/e05"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/calendar_button_selector"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#D9DBD7" >
       >

            </Button>
            <!--
  <Button
    android:id="@+id/e06"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:background="@drawable/calendar_button_selector"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
      android:textColor="#D9DBD7" > >
  </Button>

            -->
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/next_week"
        android:layout_width="50sp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#F2F2F2"
        android:src="@drawable/barrrow113" >
    </ImageView>
  </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lytContent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/txtCopyright"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lytTitlebar"
    android:background="@drawable/border2"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listfourthscrMenu"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:dividerHeight="1dip"
        android:fadeScrollbars="true"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/listview_selector" />
      </LinearLayout>

      </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You just need to keep that bottom layout in Scroll..

Comment: how???  its say scrollview handle only 1 linearlayout

Comment: No scroll can handle any layout but ScrollView can have only single child. use Scrollview child as Linear or Relative layout and add other controls in that Child(Linear or Relative Layout).

Comment: just edit my code please i want tomake scrollable screen after three tab help me ipaste my complete xml code above

Comment: It not possible to use scrollview in that layout because listview cannot use in scrollview...

Comment: @user2686011 is there ListView in bottom side..??

Comment: my complete code is above

Comment: i paste my screenshot and complete xml code above

Comment: @user2686011 in android it is not possible to keep scroll with in scroll.. as ListView has default functionality to scroll so we can not keep listview in scrollview.

Comment: what about all scren scrolable??

Comment: i just want make scrollview and shw all data in listview when scrolling  do not want listview scrolll

Comment: @user2686011 I suggest you use bring all of the <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttonlayout" ...> </LinearLayout> into a view. After that, the ListView addHeader which is a view above. So it will resolve your problem.

Comment: how? please edit my code

Comment: I will answer you because of litte comment character

Comment: but some expert also edit cdoe and paste it somewhere opton for advisor in stackoverflow u use that option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: You change your layout only like this: (Bring apart of your layout to another file xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="#ffffff"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

   <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/editbackground" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnback"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/myback" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtCaption2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnback"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="Menues"
        android:textSize="17dp" >
    </TextView>
   </RelativeLayout>

   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

       <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgfourth1"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="33"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:src="@drawable/amlet1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgfourth2"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="33"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:src="@drawable/lnch1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgfourth3"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="33"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:src="@drawable/supper" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border4"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtfth1"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="33"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Breakfast" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtfth2"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="33"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Lunch" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtfth3"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="33"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Supper" />
    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lytContent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/txtCopyright"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lytTitlebar"
    android:background="@drawable/border2"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listfourthscrMenu"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:dividerHeight="1dip"
        android:fadeScrollbars="true"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/listview_selector" />
  </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Create a new file header.xml and paste all that you cut above.

In your code when you inflate layout:
ListView listView = findViewById(....);
You create a headerView: View headerView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.header, null);
And then listView.addHeaderView(headerView);

ofcourse every view in header view like ImageView last_month you can search by lastMonthView = headerView.findViewById(....);

Is it clear?

Comment: No! do not use ScrollView with ListView.

Comment: u  not getting my point i want to make scren scrolable below this ui http://imgur.com/KKtDIu1 do not want listview scrollable just display all element of listview when scrolling UI

Comment: below or under. the  imgur.com/KKtDIu1 is always on top, and everything scroll under this???

Comment: below this http://imgur.com/KKtDIu1 all ui is scrollable listview doestnot scrollitself  all screen scrolling and show til last element of listview

Comment: yes ur right i want to scroll everything below this screen http://imgur.com/KKtDIu1

Comment: I will make my question clearly. You split all layout to make http://imgur.com/yiuGXhZ to another file named: header.xml. And you follow my answer. It declare it's your point if you want everything scroll below the top view.

Comment: im so confusing u say alll abpve xml code lace innew file header.xml thenhow is scroling???? where i place <ScrollView> ???

Comment: In my answer, all code I post is your main layout. And part of code you split is brought to another xml layout file named: header.xml. You  can read my above comment.

Comment: what is  context in ur code   LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.header, null)

Comment: LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.header, null)

Comment: If you write this code in your activity, activity is your context. LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.header, null);

Comment: i did what u say but application is force to close

Comment: what xml file i show on set contentview? header or original

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.fourthscreen);

Comment: Resolve all error, and you have your point :). And read carefully my answer. All view in  imgur.com/yiuGXhZ MUST BE find BY HEADERVIEW.
Using headerView.findViewById(...), do not use only findViewById.

Comment: it say  R.id.last_month can not be resolve idid like this 
last_month = (ImageView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.last_month);

Comment: i did exactly what u saying but  last_month = (ImageView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.last_month);  it say R.id.last_month) cannot be resolve

Comment: do you delete all view you bring to header file (in original file). If yes, is your header.xml build error?

Comment: yes, do not keep any layout that you bring to headear.xml. Delete them in original file. My answer above cut that, you can see.

Comment: http://gdurl.com/814Z/download
First I think you should study layout, and then use header in listview. This project above help you to understand it. Good luck.

Comment: element whichare in original file is displayed elemnt are in header.xml are not shown

Comment: just tell me where calling header.xml elemnts in original xml file? how both are show with combine???

Comment: Did you run my project I've send you above? gdurl.com/814Z/download

Comment: listMainMenu = (ListView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.listfourthscrMenu);
  listMainMenu.addHeaderView(headerView);

Comment: No!, oh my god. ListView is found in activity. HeaderView does not contain it. listMainMenu = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listfourthscrMenu); listMainMenu.addHeaderView(headerView);

Comment: Yes, in my answer, the listview is still there.You only bring xml layout of imgur.com/yiuGXhZ to header.xml. Pls run my project and study

Comment: this is original screen  http://imgur.com/yUKds1l and use  ur code screen look like this http://imgur.com/vwJmjBZ

Comment: now is work i cut all code form original file except list and and place in header.xml now is work:)

Comment: suppose if i want to add progress bar in screen for waiting for url parsing data where i place progressbar? in original file or in header.xml file???

Comment: First vote for my answer
Second if you have another question, pls create a new thread.

Comment: no just tell me simple if i want to add progressbar in this layout which xml file i add progressbar? in originalfile where listview or in header.xml file???

Comment: I think you should put progress in main xml file, not in header. Because header can be scrolled up and user not see it.

Comment: i want to show data in in listview after url parse data from server until show progressbar on main screen so where i place that progressbar in main.xml or in header.xml???

Comment: +1 @hieuxit for your amazing patience. You've got a super power dude :D